# This autoloader loads only the first class

Tags: php, oop, spl-autoload-register, psr-0

I have the following autoloader, that for some reason is loading only the first class.

Here is the Autoloader class

```
<?php 
 class AutoloaderException extends Exception{}

class AutoLoader
{
    private $classDir; 
    private $namespace; 
    public $dirSeparatorSymbol = '\\'; 

    public function __construct($namespace, $classDir)
    {
        $this->classDir = $classDir; 
        $this->namespace = $namespace;

    }

    private function load($class)
    {

        $include_path = str_replace($this->dirSeparatorSymbol, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $this->classDir);

        $classFilename = strtolower(substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1) . '.php');

        if(file_exists($include_path.$classFilename)){
            require $include_path.$classFilename;

            return true; 
        }


        throw new AutoloaderException('Class '.$classFilename. ' could not be loaded'); 
    }   

    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }
}
```

While the above works, but only loads one class at a time. So, in the below example.
For every registered path/class only first will only get loaded.

```
$b = new Autoloader('mercury\venus\earth', __DIR__.'/mercury/venus/earth/');
$b->register();

$a = new Autoloader('bar\tar', __DIR__.'/foo/bar/tar/');
$a->register();


$x = new bar\tar;

$y = new mercury\venus\earth;
```

What could be the problem for this?

Comment: It's written to load only one class at a time, which is what most autoloaders are designed to do..... only load the classes that are actually needed, and only at the point in the code where they are needed

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't think I said it correctly. My above script, disregards entirely `$y new mercury\venus\earth` and does not load this class. It only loads the first. I am convinced this class has a problem. Because I can use 'spl_autoload_register' by itself, and it will work just fine.

Comment: What is an actual error? Where is the register method?

Comment: @sectus There register method is there. Just scroll down a little, and you'll see it. This is the error I am getting. `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'AutoloaderException' with message 'Class tar.php could not be loaded' in /var/test/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: AutoLoader->load('bar\\tar') #1 /var/test/index.php(48): spl_autoload_call('bar\\tar') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/skillz/test/index.php on line 31`

Comment: @CONtext , sorry. Why do not use standart autoloader of psr-0 or use composer for this?

Comment: @sectus That is the main problem. I am trying to [understand](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58948/how-can-this-autoloader-be-improved) all about autoloaders, so I wanted to make my own, since I can't figure out whats what, when looking at the psr-0. Eventually, when I am done making this code work and psr-0 compliant, I will use those instead. This is just a learning curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there must be multiple autoload functions, spl_autoload_register() allows for this. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions, and runs through each of them in the order they are defined.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

It's queue. Second autoload function would run if first autoload function did not define a class.

So, you do not need to throw an exception in your autoload method because it would prevent launching second autoload method in your autoload queue.